# In this example, the class index always outputs 1 even if the person in the camera changes. How can I make the index change according to the person?

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv, keras, face-recognition

I want the class index to change according to the person who appears on the camera. I trained pictures of 2 different people using the Teachable Machine platform, and I use it as 'keras_model.h5'. However, when I run the program the class index is always equals to 1, so it always outputs the same person's name.

OUTPUTS:
When the first person comes to the camera, the program prints this

```
CLASSINDEX: [1]
PREDICTION: [[0.025007 0.97499305]]
1/1 [================================] - 0s 25ms/step
```

When the second person comes to the camera, the program prints this

```
CLASSINDEX: [1]
PREDICTION: [[2.5015764e-04 9.9974984e-01]]
1/1 [================================] - 0s 20ms/step
```

- 

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np
import cv2
from keras.models import load_model
import numpy as np


facedetect = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

cap=cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(3, 640)
cap.set(4, 480)
font=cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX


model = load_model('keras_model.h5')


def get_className(classNo):
    if classNo==0:
        return "numan"
    elif classNo==1:
        return "tony"

while True:
    sucess, imgOrignal=cap.read()
    faces = facedetect.detectMultiScale(imgOrignal,1.3,5)
    for x,y,w,h in faces:
        crop_img=imgOrignal[y:y+h,x:x+h]
        img=cv2.resize(crop_img, (224,224))
        img=img.reshape(1, 224, 224, 3)
        prediction=model.predict(img)
        classIndex = np.argmax(prediction,axis=1)
        probabilityValue=np.amax(prediction)
        print("CLASSINDEX:",classIndex)
        print("PREDICTION:",prediction)
        if classIndex==0:
            cv2.rectangle(imgOrignal,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)
            cv2.rectangle(imgOrignal, (x,y-40),(x+w, y), (0,255,0),-2)
            cv2.putText(imgOrignal, str(get_className(classIndex)),(x,y-10), font, 0.75, 
(255,255,255),1, cv2.LINE_AA)
        elif classIndex==1:
            cv2.rectangle(imgOrignal,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)
            cv2.rectangle(imgOrignal, (x,y-40),(x+w, y), (0,255,0),-2)
            cv2.putText(imgOrignal, str(get_className(classIndex)),(x,y-10), font, 0.75, 
(255,255,255),1, cv2.LINE_AA)

        cv2.putText(imgOrignal,str(round(probabilityValue*100, 2))+"%" ,(180, 75), font, 
0.75, (255,0,0),2, cv2.LINE_AA)
    cv2.imshow("Result",imgOrignal)
    k=cv2.waitKey(1)
    if k==ord('q'):
        break


cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: maybe your model is wrong.

Comment: But it works good on teachable machine platform. It differentiates two different person. Also, as I shared above outputs are different for different person.

Comment: your output it totally different - it displays `CLASS: ...` but you don't have word `CLASS:` in your code. it seems you runs different code.

Comment: you are resizing and using haar model to get faces. resizing decreases the input data validation. haar can give you bad results since its old and not really trusted. More important than that; your training processes/steps can be wrong